# Does there exist an ordering-functor?

Tags: ct.category-theory, order-theory

This sounds like a very silly question which should have have a negative answer but I don't see an argument. The precise question is this:

> Does there exist a covariant functor $ord$ from the category of sets and functions to the category of totally ordered sets and increasing functions such that every set $X$ is the underlying set of $ord(X)$?

---

Of course, I assume the axiom of choice so that every set can be even well-ordered. Since the well-ordering is based on rather arbitrary choices there does not seem to be a reason why it should be in any sense "compatible" with all functions. My guess is that such a functor does not even exist in the subcategory of finite sets.

Comment: For a totally ordered finite set the only automorphism is the identity so you will likely have problems

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I can see that your reason works for faithful functors. Why would it work for arbitrary functors?

Comment: Sure, all automorphisms are send to the identity -- why is this a problem?

Comment: In more detail, any such functor will have to either collapse all the endomorphisms of a finite set $X$ to the identity or send all the permutations to the identity and all other endomorphisms to some other idempotent endomorphism.of X  This is because the monoid of all self maps on a finite set is generated by the symmetric group and the idempotent which collapses two elements and fixes the rest. I find it hard to believe you can do this in a nice functorial way,

Comment: "increasing" means preserving $\le$, or preserving $<$?

Comment: @YCor Increansing means $\le$ preserving (for strictly increasing the question is trivial because strictly increasing functions between totally ordered sets are injective).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Conceptual answer.**

There can be no such functor.  Let $C$ be any concrete category of finite sets and mappings such that the only automorphisms in $C$ are trivial.  I claim there is no underlying set preserving functor $F$ from the category $\mathbf{FSet}$ of finite sets to $C$.  The category of finite totally ordered sets and order-preserving maps is of this form.

Let us call the *rank* of a mapping the size of its image.

First note in the category $\mathbf{FSet}$ of finite sets, all idempotents split.  That is, if $e\colon X\to X$ is an idempotent then there are morphisms $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to X$ with $gf=e$ and $fg=1_Y$ for some finite set $Y$. Here you can take $Y$ to be the image of $e$ and take $g$ to be the inclusion and $f$ to be the "corestriction" of $e$.  Since $F(f)F(g)=F(fg)=F(1_Y)=1_Y$, we deduce that $F(f)$ is surjective and $F(g)$ is injective and so $F(e)=F(g)F(f)$ has image of size $|Y|$. Thus $F$ preserves the ranks of idempotents, i.e., rank $e$ = rank $F(e)$.

Next note that if $|X|\geq 3$, then there is an idempotent of rank  $|X|-2$ which is a product of conjugate rank $|X|-1$ idempotents.  To ease notation assume $|X|=n$.  For $i\neq j$ let $e_{i,j}$ be the rank $n-1$ idempotent with $e_{i,j}(i)=i=e_{i,j}(j)$ and which fixes all other elements.  Let $k\neq i,j$.  Then $f=e_{i,j}e_{j, k}$ sends $i,j,k$ to $i$ and fixes all other elements and so is a rank $n-2$ idempotent.

Notice that $e_{i,j}$ and $e_{j,k}$ are conjugate by the permutation $(i,j,k)$:  we have $e_{j,k} = (i,j,k)e_{i,j}(k,j,i)$.  Since $F((i,j,k))=1_X$, we must have $F(e_{i,j})=F(e_{j,k})$.  Since these are idempotents, $F(f)=f(e_{i,j})$, contradicting that $F$ preserves rank of idempotents.

**Original answer.** I think there is no functor from finite sets to finite totally ordered sets with order preserving maps preserving underlying sets. Here is a proof.  Let $F$ be such a functor.  It must send every permutation of a finite set $X$ to the identity as there are no non-trivial automorphisms of a finite totally ordered set. Next I claim that every non-invertible endomorphism $f\colon X\to X$ has $F(f)$ a constant mapping.  For this, I use the well known fact that the monoid of self-maps of $X$ is generated by the symmetric group $S_X$ and any idempotent $e$ with image of size $|X|-1$.  Hence, since $F(S_X)$ is the identity, every non-invertible mapping gets sent to $F(e)$.  But if $f\colon X\to X$ is a constant mapping, we have that $f= gh$ with $h\colon X\to \{1\}$ and $g\colon \{1\}\to X$.  Thus $F(f)=F(g)F(h)$ has image of size $1$.   Thus $F(e)$ above must have image of size $1$ and so every non-invertible mapping of $X$ to $X$ is sent to a constant mapping.  This is a problem.

Consider $f\colon \{1,2\}\to \{1,2,3\}$ given by the inclusion and $g\colon \{1,2,3\}\to \{1,2\}$ given by $g(1)=1$, $g(2)=2$ and $g(3)=2$.  Then $gf$ is the identity but $fg$ is non-invertible.  Thus $F(gf)$ is an identify mapping and $F(fg)$ is a constant mapping, which is impossible as $gf=gfgf$ and so $F(gf)=F(g)F(fg)F(f)$ is both a constant map and an identity for a two element set.

Comment: The fact that the endormorphisms of a finite set are generated by the symmetric group and an idempotent whose image misses one element can be found in Lemma 4.12.27 of my book with John Rhodes, The q-theory of finite semigroups, for instance.

Comment: Actually there is already no functor from the full subcategory consisting of 1,2, and 3 element sets where I guess my claims about generation are obvious.

Comment: The "conceptual version" shows there are problems even if your concrete category C has automorphism groups of size 1 or 2 since my conjugator is an even permutation.  So allowing both order preserving and order reversing maps wouldn't help.

Comment: It’s worth noting also that if we restrict the domain to just the *groupoid* of finite sets (or indeed some larger class of sets), then assuming global choice, such a functor does exist. For each set, pick a well-ordering; then send each isomorphism of sets to the unique order-isomorphism between the given orderings of those sets.  This shows that the consideration of non-bijective maps in the answer is unavoidable.